# Updating column value based on if the value is a substring of another column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Suppose I have two tables in the database:

**Table_1**

```
Column_1  |  Column_2    | Column_3

1            End Table     NULL
2            BENQ Monitor  NULL
3            Tao Lamp      NULL
```

**Table_2**

```
Column_1 | Column_2

Table      Wooden Table 
Monitor    Computer Monitor          
Lamp       LED Lamp
```

And I want to update **Column_3** in **Table_1** as follows by checking if **Column_2** in **Table_1** contains the substring given in **Column_1**, **Table_2**.

```
Column_1  |  Column_2    | Column_3

1            End Table     Wooden Table
2            BENQ Monitor  Computer Monitor
3            Tao Lamp      LED Lamp
```

How would I go about doing this? I have tried the below but it's giving me an "invalid identifier" error.

```
UPDATE Table_1
SET Table_1.Column_3 = Table_2.Column_2
WHERE Table_1.Column_2 LIKE '%' + Table_2.Column_1 + '%';
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: The error is caused by using `+`  for concatenation. Oracle uses `||` for that (**two** vertical bars). After you fix that, though, you may get false matches - `'Computer Training'` will match whatever you have for `'Train'` (`'Toy Train'` or whatever).

Comment: Thanks for noting that. Re your second point, the domain of the input values for Column_2, Table 1 should not trigger any erroneous matches but that is certainly useful to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE Table_1
    SET Table_1.Column_3 = (SELECT Table_2.Column_2
                            FROM Table_2
                            WHERE Table_1.Column_2 LIKE '%' || Table_2.Column_1 || '%'
                           );
```

Comment: Your answer fixes everything - except the obvious mistake in the original query. `+` for concatenation? In Oracle?